# check the count on Queried fieldset

Tags: soql

I want to go through a fieldset of a child object. If it returns any value, that is, if count is 1 then I want to change a picklist value on the parent.
The code snippet for the save is:

```
public pageReference saveRecord(){
    Intake__c objData1;
    upsert intake;
    String query = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getColorFields()) {
        query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
    }
    query += 'Id FROM Intake__c where Case__c = :caseID order by LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1';

    objData1=Database.query(query);

    **//need to check the above query returns more than 0, if more than 0**

            caseitem.Intake_Status__c='Red';
        }
```

Please modify the code and help me

Comment: Why do the fields you are querying matter if you only care about non-zero count?

Comment: I have 3 child fieldsets, i want to put the parent on different status depending on the childs fields.  Example, in childs fieldset  red, if returns any value then the status of the parent becomes red, if red fieldset is empty and yellow fieldset returns not null then parent status becomes yellow.

Comment: Your where clause is always the same, meaning you will always get the same number of child records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to return a list and count the size of that list, eg:

```
public pageReference saveRecord(){
    Intake__c[] intakes = new Intake__c[]{};
    upsert intake;
    String query = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getColorFields()) {
        query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
    }
    query += 'Id FROM Intake__c where Case__c = :caseID order by LastModifiedDate DESC';

    intakes=Database.query(query);
    if (intakes.size() > 0) {
        caseitem.Intake_Status__c='Red';
    }
}
```